# How to add overlay on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am building an iOS app using Swift which requires QR code scanner functionality.

I have implemented a QR code scanner using AVFoundation, right now my capture screen looks same as a video recording screen i.e. `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` shows what is being captured by the camera.

But since it is a QR code scanner and not a regular image or video capture, I would like my `VideoPreviewLayer` to look like this: 
[image: camera overlay screenshot]

I understand this can be achieved by adding another `VideoPreviewLayer` on top of one `VideoPreviewLayer`.

My questions are:

1. How do I add the borders only to the edges in the upper (or smaller) preview layer?
2. How do I change the brightness level for the `VideoPreviewLayer` in the background?
3. How to ignore media captured by the the background layer?

Comment: I would mix the the tutorial frameview suggested by @Singh and use this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44282738/3900902 to create the corners. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Paulo : the tutorial frameview suggested by Singh ?

Comment: Oh they removed their answer. Here is the tutorial for that: http://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/. As far as the gradient layer, I am not that great at iOS/swift, but I assume you would add a sub layer with a lower opacity

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use another VideoPreviewLayer. Instead you should add two sublayers - one for the masked background area and one for the corners.

Have a look at the source code in this [repo](https://github.com/gaebel/scanner-overlay) for an example.

To limit the video capturing to the masked area you have to set the `rectOfInterest` of your `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`.

```
let rectOfInterest = videoPreviewLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: rect)
metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = rectOfInterest
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: you can use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` for video capturing, create another `CALayer()` and use `layer.insertSublayer(..., above: ...)` to insert your "custom" layer above the video layer, and by custom I mean just yet another `CALayer` with let say

```
layer.contents = spinner.cgImage
```

Here's a bit more [detailed instructions](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/08/04/swift-put-overlay-on-top-of-avcapturevideopreviewlayer/#more-381)